# when it is necessary to define a second payroll in oracle hrms

Tags: oracle

i am currently learning oracle HRMS payroll and i want to know about a scenario when we need to create 2 setups of oracle HRMS payroll instead of a single setup. For example we need to create a 2nd business group setup if
we want to generate automatic employee numbers for one company and manual employee numbers for other company.

Comment: in my opinion if we have these situations we need to setup a different payroll                              if payroll frequency is different 
if we are dealig with multiple currencies
if we have different business groups 
if we have Different GL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about legal entities for a business group, as a starting point.

Also the legislation (country) is linked to a business group, so a company active in 2 countries, will probably need two business groups, in case Oracle supports both legislations.

Comment: if we have different frequencies for employees than we should define two different payrolls or one payroll setup is ok?

Comment: First you have the question of defining the number of business groups. One of the most complicated, but important, setup decisions.Next comes the setup of payroll(s) within a business group. The payroll inherits the legislation of the business group. When frequency is different, one has to define a payroll per frequency (weekly, 4-weekly, monthly, ...). But even with the same frequency, it sometimes makes sense to setup multiple payrolls, to split the processes and the population (white colors versus blue colors) ..